# How to read the text of an old MediaWiki page from a SQL backup?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I have a SQL backup of an old Wiki page (approx. version 1.16) and would like to reuse the content of some of these pages for a newer project. Instead of reinstalling the complete wiki, I would like to fetch some parts the old content from these SQL files, but I have not found the content pages in my SQL backup. My guess is that page content is stored in "text" table, but this table rows are binary coded, so I'm not able to directly read the content.

Is my guess right that wiki page content is in table "text"? - If yes, how can I read the row content?

Comment: Good point - This old Wiki was used with MySQL.

Comment: you'd have to restore the database and then query it

Comment: The question is: is table "text" the table where the content is? If yes, how can I query the binary blob fields?

Comment: well if you restored the database and ran a query on that table, you'd know the answer. If the data in there is still binary, you'll need to know what kind of binary format it is, so you can decode it. Maybe base64, or who knows what else.

Comment: The manual is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout . If you're asking how to restore a database from a dump, or how to read SQL files without importing them into a database, a more specific question may be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the configuration. The page content might be in the [`text`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table) table (that's the default) or [elsewhere](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:External_Storage). The `text` table [might be](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBmysql5) binary UTF-8 (default) or a native string. In the first case, just do a conversion (`CONVERT(text.old_text USING utf8)` or something like that).